# Recommended way to send inserted data [to database] back to application

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest, slim

I am developing a Rest web service. 
For some Requests I need to Insert the data in database and send back the same data if the Insertion is successful.

Which among the following is the right way to do this and **WHY** ?:

**[ Method 1 ]** While sending back the data do I need to just check whether the *INSERT* query has been successfully executed or not and if Yes, then send the same data which I received in Request back as Response (without SELECT the data from database).

**OR**

**[ Method 2 ]** After inserting the data I have to get the Primary Key of inserted record and use it to *SELECT* all the data, and then send it as response ?

Comment: I think the Method 1 is good. As I see, Method 2 has a problem. Let say it inserted successfully. But, when you get last inserted record, it might have add another record. Go with method  1

Comment: if data received in request is good enough to send back, running second query (_SELECT_) is  meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

typicaly when you developing a rest api in insert case a good opition is do not answarectoting as response body 201 as http srarus an feel the location http header whit the link to the new resource.

then you could fire a get to the location and retrive all the data.
this approch save bandwitd in case this aspect is a critical asoect.

hohewer another good option if the bandwitd isn't a problem you can consider the option of return the result on the response body.

it don't exist a 4igth answare is a tradeoff that you may consider in your api design.

i hope that this can help you